# Which e-mail app to display as Plain Text (text/plain mime part)?

Tags: android, email

I'm looking for an email app on android (my phone runs Android 10) that I can configure to display only the **text/plain MIME part** of the messages I receive. (I don't want to see the HTML part as it doesn't contain all the information that is in the plain text part)

Do you know any such app ? I haven't found any yet.

Thanks